# A workaround for custom and "dynamic" notification sounds

Tags: ios, audio, apple-push-notifications, bundle, customization

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6), we can read

> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that
>   iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app.
>   The sound files must be in the main bundle of the client app.

My app evolves around notifications, like many other apps, and I would really like to have the ability to add sounds later on, or at least to have some kind of control over them. The best scenario would be :

On launch, my app checks the sound database online and downloads any updates.

But obviously if all the sounds have to be in the bundle, this can't be done.

I have over 400Mb of sounds, and as obvious as this sounds, this is also too much for the app store, and that's why I'd need some control from the user, to not download all the sounds.

Is there any possible workaround so that I can play sounds written on disk and not in bundle? Or any other possibility you might think of so I can play a custom push notification sound?

If that is of any help, my app works 100% online, so if there is a solution, it can be server-related.

I understand that I'm most probably get a "No" as the best answer, but I need to make sure.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can place custom sounds in the `Library/Sounds` folder.

[Preparing Custom Alert Sounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)

Answer (score 1):

If your app wants to be in App Store, then you should follow the apple documentation. That is to say, we can only play the sound from the main bundle.
And we also could **not** modify the main bundle dynamically. Because it's encrypted.
So I'm afraid you could not go this way. But I suggest to upload the whole app to App Store if you could sacrifice the sound file dynamically update feature.

Comment: Yeah but I just don't like having my users to download that much data, specially if they're not gonna use it all.
But I  guess that's what I'll have to do !

Comment: @Zil， yeah this is a pity. Hope Apple could improve in the future.